# Share arguments list between multiple PHPSTORM_META\expectedArguments

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying to use the `.phpstorm.meta.php` file to manually define intellisense to a function I use to get and set dynamic settings in the database.

So imagine a class that looks like this:

```php
class Setting
{
    public function get(string $key) {
        // ...
    }

    public function set(string $key, $value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, to define the possible values that can go in the `$key` argument, I can do this in the meta file:

```php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    expectedArguments(
        \App\Models\Setting::get(),
        0,
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'baz'
    );

    expectedArguments(
        \App\Models\Setting::set(),
        0,
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'baz'
    );
}
```

The thing is, the list of possible values is quite extensive, and duplicating them is a pain. Is there a way to define these values on multiple functions using the same statement? Or maybe put them in an array and use it somehow? I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

*PhpStorm version: 2021.3.3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, PhpStorm's Advanced Metadata has **named sets of arguments** feature that does just that: allows to define sets of arguments using `registerArgumentsSet()` and then use it in multiple places using `argumentsSet()`.

It is used for quite a few core PHP functions, for example `ini_get()` and `ini_set()` etc.

In your case it will be something like this:

```php
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    registerArgumentsSet('ModelSettingArgs', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz');

    expectedArguments(
        \App\Models\Setting::get(),
        0,
        argumentsSet('ModelSettingArgs')
    );

    expectedArguments(
        \App\Models\Setting::set(),
        0,
        argumentsSet('ModelSettingArgs')
    );
}
```

PhpStorm Advanced Metadata help page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#arguments-set